# Pseudo element from edge of screen to edge of container

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to realise a website (using bootstrap 4), that has a gradient line that comes from the title, and extends to the left edge of the container. I've figured out how to do this, but the gradient will never show in full. I've created a wrapping `div.overflow-hidden` that spans the full width of the page, and has `overflow-x: hidden;`. The gradient line is an `::after` pseudo-element on the `h1` element.
Is there a pure html/css solution to make sure the full gradient always shows? The location of the heading on the page is variable, and since it's in a container, I can't give the pseudo element a fixed width, since it's dependant on the screen's resolution. See code below for my attempt at this:
**Expected result:**
[image: Title with line and image detail]

```css
.overflow-hidden {
  overflow-x: hidden!important;
  width: 100%;
}

.title-detail {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.title-detail::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 0.25rem;
  right: calc(100% + 2.25rem);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, rgb(72, 184, 171) 0%, rgb(97, 157, 191) 100%);
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.column-count-2 {
  column-count: 2;
  column-gap: 2rem;
  column-rule: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="overflow-hidden">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
      <div class="col-12 col-md-10 col-xl-8">
        <h1 class="title-detail">title of page</h1>
        <div class="column-count-2">
          <p class="lead">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin risus metus, lacinia sed erat vitae, dictum ullamcorper urna.</p>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin risus metus, lacinia sed erat vitae, dictum ullamcorper urna.</p>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin risus metus, lacinia sed erat vitae, dictum ullamcorper urna.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/aq9Laaew/170282/)

Comment: I don't understand what the actual issue is. Do you mean there's a gap between the line and container?

Comment: The line is positioned like it should be, but the gradient isn't visible from start to finish. A big chunk of the gradient line is cut off at the edge of the screen. I can't think of any way the gradient can be shown in full, while still making it flexible enough to work on all resolutions, and any position the heading may have on the page

Comment: line is very small, so it is not looking like a gradient and right you are applying huge so its hided in extreme left section

Comment: @charankumar It is a gradient, it's a subtle one, I'll give you that, but it is a gradient and must remain a gradient. For the designer it's a very important detail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Updated the answer**

I think this will work for you:

Just changed `.title-detail::after {width: calc(((100vw - 1170px)/2) - 10px);}` and it worked fine for me. For proving my point I have removed the `.overflow-hidden`.

> Explained - `.title-detail::after {width: calc(((100vw - 1170px)/2) -
>   10px);}` that is *.title-detail::after {width: calc(((Screen Width -
>   .container width[this has to handiled through mediaquery with
>   bootstrap] )/margins of both side) - small gap handled);}*

```css
/*.overflow-hidden {
  overflow-x: hidden!important;
  width: 100%;
}*/

.title-detail {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.title-detail::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  width: calc(((100vw - 1170px)/2) - 10px);
  height: 0.25rem;
  right: calc(100% + 2.25rem);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, rgb(72, 184, 171) 0%, rgb(97, 157, 191) 100%);
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.column-count-2 {
  column-count: 2;
  column-gap: 2rem;
  column-rule: none;
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .title-detail::after {
    width: calc(((100vw - 970px)/2) - 10px);
  }
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .title-detail::after {
    width: calc(((100vw - 750px)/2) - 10px);
  }
}
```

```html
<!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
<link href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">

<div class="overflow-hidden">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
      <div class="col-12 col-md-10 col-xl-8">
        <h1 class="title-detail">title of page</h1>
        <div class="column-count-2">
          <p class="lead">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin risus metus, lacinia sed erat vitae, dictum ullamcorper urna.</p>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin risus metus, lacinia sed erat vitae, dictum ullamcorper urna.</p>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin risus metus, lacinia sed erat vitae, dictum ullamcorper urna.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope this solve your issue.
*This works fine in Firefox chrome and safari.*

Comment: Thanks for your help, but this doesn't solve my problem. The gradient doesn't run to the edge of the screen.

Comment: @Connor It does. Please use full screen on the snippet and you will see.

Comment: No, it does not. Look here: https://i.imgur.com/IXOHvVn.png. You're basing the width of the line on the width of the heading, which is variable, based on how much content the heading has.

Comment: @Connor please check if the new answer work for you, I will finish the media query needed at that time.

Comment: Oh, haven't thought of using the container width in a `calc()`. Thank you very much! I can fix the rest of the media queries myself, I don't want you to go through more trouble than you need to.

Comment: @Connor it's k I have updated the answer with the media queries if there is any issue please do inform me as I am little busy to test it properly :)